# How to validate a excel file in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I am  new to mule.I need to input a excel file to mule from a watch folder.i need to check wheather,that excel file is valid or not.

What is the best way to validate an excel file in mule

Answer (score 0):

The EE edition has Datamapper which has out-of-the-box Excel support: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/DataMapper+Excel+to+JSON+Example

I suppose you could attempt to parse the CSV using Datamapper and transform to check validiity.

But you can of course create a custom filter(http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Using+Filters#UsingFilters-CreatingCustomFilters) or component with something like Apache POI: http://poi.apache.org/